# Configuring IIS 8.5 via PowerShell: how remove inherit folder authorization

Tags: powershell, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, ftp-server

I'm deploying an FTP Server with TLS on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2) with some success but now I'm stuck at this situation.

I can assign FTP Authorizations to the root FTP folder via Powershell using the following method (which reflects inside C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config exactly in the same way as GUI (IIS Management Console) does it).
PS step for this is:

```
$CsvFtpGroups = $FTPGROUPS -join ','
$Param = @{
    Filter   = "/system.ftpServer/security/authorization"
    Value    = @{
        accessType  = "Allow"
        roles       = "$($CsvFtpGroups)"
        permissions = "Read"
    }
    PSPath   = 'IIS:\'
    Location = $FTPSiteName
}
Add-WebConfiguration @Param
```

and XML result in applicationHost.config is this:

```
<location path="FTPServer">
    <system.ftpServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="GROUP1,GROUP2" permissions="Read" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.ftpServer>
</location>
```

---

Now the issue:

I want to remove inheritance for the previous to all subfolders because I need them to have specific authorisations which will be configured next.

When I use IIS Mgmt Console and manually remove this inherited authorisation from all subfolders I get this inside applicationHost.config:

```
<location path="FTPServer/Folder1">
    <system.ftpServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="" roles="GROUP1,GROUP2" permissions="Read" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.ftpServer>
</location>
```

And I can't add anything similar via PowerShell.

I've already tried this to no avail:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PsPath "IIS:\" -Location "$($FTPSiteName)/$($FTPSubFolder1)" -Filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -Name "." -AtElement @{users="";roles="$($roles)";permissions="Read"}
```

And also tried 'Adding' a 'remove' statement:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -PsPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "FTPServer/Folder1" -Filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization/remove" -name "." -value @{users="";roles="GROUP1,GROUP2";permissions="Read"}
```

And finally also tried with:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "FTPServer/Folder1" -Name "system.ftpServer.security.authorization.remove" -Value @{users="";roles="GROUP1,GROUP2";permissions="Read"}
```

None of these worked. What can I try next?

Comment: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery Follow "Getting Started" to install IISAdministration, and then follow https://blogs.iis.net/jeonghwan/how-to-use-iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets-to-configure-iis-configuration-settings to study how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you with severalexamples, you can modify some parts according to your needs.

This statement can add new authorization to subfile.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'FTPServer/Folder1' -filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -name "." -value @{accessType='Allow';roles='GROUP3';permissions='Read,Write'}
```

This statement can remove the authorization rules of the sub-file inherited from the root folder.

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'FTPServer/Folder1' -filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -name "." -AtElement @{users='';roles='GROUP1,GROUP2';permissions='1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and @Bruce Zhang. I ended up using 'Clear-WebConfiguration' (twice due to an already reported bug) to clear inheritance, and then adding custom authorization to the sub-folders afterwards.

But I can confirm that Bruce's suggestion:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'FTPServer/Folder1' -filter "system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -name "." -AtElement @{users='';roles='GROUP1,GROUP2';permissions='1'}
```

works perfectly!

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that your problem has been resolved, you can mark this answer so that it can help others with similar problems.